# Alternatives To Global Variables in C++

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces, logic, global-variables

I need to set a variable in the main function and access it from a different function in the same file. I can not pass it to the function because it means changing the entire code structure, which is not an option. To avoid declaring a global variable I crated a namespace and I want to check if this is a good programming practice or is there a cleaner way to do it.
This is the code:

```
namespace mylocalnamespace{
    int myglobalvar;
}

static void myFunc()
{
    ..... some code
    operationX(mylocalnamespace::myglobalvar);
    ..... some code

}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ..... some code
   mylocalnamespace::myglobalvar = atoi(argv[0]);
   ..... some code
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to pass the argument, then the only option is to put it into a scope both functions have access to,. so namespace scope.  A singleton can also be a safe way to do this.

Comment: Putting a global variable from the global namespace in to a `mylocalnamespace` namespace like that is still a global variable.  But now it's a global variable in a namespace.

Comment: If your code structure is wrong, you'll spend lots of time working around the mistakes. Better to fix it now.

Comment: Looks like that Lily is fighting with legacy code. Problem is that to much information has been striped from question. @Lily please provide more details! What kind of compatibility you ave to maintain: binary/source? Are threads involved? Who access this global state: is it changed from call to call or other function access that state? Is you function actual with no arguments? If not provide information about arguments. Make sure that it is clear for everyone what is fixed what has been stripped what is explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alternatives To Global Variables in C++

In the example, function argument is a good alternative to avoid a global variable:

```
static void myFunc(int mylocalvar)
{
    ..... some code
    operationX(mylocalvar);
    ..... some code

}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ..... some code
   mylocalvar = atoi(argv[0]);
   ..... some code
   myFunc(mylocalvar);
}
```

---

> I can not pass it to the function

Oh well, then you have to use a global variable.

Since you apparently use it in a function with internal linkage, you could improve slightly by using global with internal linkage as well. This way the global won't leak to other translation units. A handy way to achieve that is an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {
    int myglobalvar;

    void myFunc() {
        // ...
```

---

> To avoid declaring a global variable I crated a namespace

Global variables are still global variables even if not in the global namespace.

Comment: The OP says they don't want to use a function parameter.

Comment: I can not pass it as a function parameter because it includes changing the structure of the code which is not an option. I was specifically asked not to change that.

Comment: @Lily Then you must use a global. You can improve it a bit by using internal linkage.

Comment: @eerorika internal linkage was the solution, thanks!